# ¿Cómo clonar un formulario con jQuery optimizando código?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

En HTML tengo un formulario básico:

```js
let numero = 1;
let nuevo = function() {
  numero++;
  jQuery('.inputs').append(`<section id="${numero}"><input type="text" name="codigo" placeholder="Ingrese Codigo"><input type="text" name="namearti" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre"><input type="text" name="cantidad" placeholder="Ingrese Cantidad"> <button class="btn-danger" onclick="eliminar(${numero})">Eliminar</button></section>`);
}

let eliminar = function(n) {
  jQuery("section").remove(`#${n}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="gestionArticulos.php">
  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" name="codigo" placeholder="Ingrese Codigo">
    <input type="text" name="namearti" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre Articulo">
    <input type="text" name="cantidad" placeholder="Ingrese Cantidad">
    <button type="button" onclick="nuevo();">Agregar</button>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="enviar">
</form>
```

Cuando me refiero a la optimización de código, es que si en algún momento debo de modificar el HTML para insertar 10 campos al formulario no tenga que reinsertar esos 10 campos dentro del jQuery, sino encontrar una manera más cómoda y dinámica, para que no tenga que "reinsertar" el mismo código HTML dentro de un append de jQuery.

Comment: y porque vas a volver a crear el formulario completo?

Comment: clonar un formulario ya existente en la página? o construir un formulario a partir de una estructura tipo array o json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es copiar los campos de `.inputs` sin tener que repetirlos en el código de JavaScript, lo que puedes hacer es duplicar el código de `.inputs` y agregarlo a un `section` detrás de `.inputs` (aunque realmente el código que estabas agregando no es el mismo porque el botón no es Agregar sino Eliminar y tendrías que cambiar su funcionalidad). Algo como esto (comentado):

```
let nuevo = function() {
  $("<section/>")                                    // crea una nueva sección
                 .insertBefore("[name='enviar']")    // insértala antes del botón de enviar (para que se vayan añadiendo en orden)
                 .append($(".inputs").html())        // añádele el código con los campos de .inputs
                 .find("button")                     // selecciona el botón de añadir
                 .attr("onclick", "eliminar(this)")  // cambia su acción a eliminar
                 .text("Eliminar");                  // y su texto también
}
```

Como puedes ver, esta solución no depende de IDs generados o variables globales para saber qué sección tienes que eliminar. Puedes usar el método [`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) de jQuery que te va a devolver el ancestro más cercano que cumpla una condición. Así cuando se pulse en el botón de Eliminar, sólo tendrías que buscar un `.closest("section")` para que te encuentre la sección que contiene los campos a borrar:

```
let eliminar = function(obj) {
  $(obj).closest("section")    // buscamos el section más cercano
        .remove();             // lo eliminamos
}
```

Con esos cambios, lo puedes ver funcionando aquí:

```js
let nuevo = function() {
  $("<section/>").insertBefore("[name='enviar']")
                 .append($(".inputs").html())
                 .find("button")
                 .attr("onclick", "eliminar(this)")
                 .text("Eliminar");
}

let eliminar = function(obj) {
  $(obj).closest("section").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="gestionArticulos.php">
  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" name="codigo" placeholder="Ingrese Codigo">
    <input type="text" name="namearti" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre Articulo">
    <input type="text" name="cantidad" placeholder="Ingrese Cantidad">
    <button type="button" onclick="nuevo();">Agregar</button>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Es excelente Alvaro Montoro, Es exactamente lo que requería, muchas gracias por tu dispoción y por el aporte, que no quizas solo a mi  si no a muchos de los que desarrollamos y a veces necesitamos de una mano. Un Saludo.